# How to Calculate a Hash of a file that is 1 Terabyte and over?

Tags: hash, large-data

So, I have a couple of system backup image files that are around 1 terabyte,
and i want to calculate fast the hash of each one of them (preferably SHA-1).

At first i tried to calculate the md5 hash, 2 hours had passed and the hash hadn't been calculated yet (something that's obvious for large files up to 1TB).

So is there any program/implementation out there that can hash a 1TB file quickly?

I have heard of Tree-Hashing that hashes parts of file simultaneously, but I haven't found any implementation so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a 1 million MB file, and your system can read this file at 100MB/s, then

- 1TB * 1000(TB/GB) = 1000 GB
- 1000GB * 1000(MB/GB) = 1 million MB
- 1 million MB/100(MB/s) = 10 thousand seconds
- 10000s/3600(s/hr) = 2.77... hr
- Therefore, a 100MB/s system has a hard floor of 2.77... hrs to even read the file in the first place, even before whatever additional total time may be required to compute a hash.

Your expectations are probably unrealistic - don't try to calculate a faster hash until you can perform a faster file read.

Comment: You are right, but i doubt my system can read the file at 100MB/s :( Are there alternative ways to read a file faster?

Comment: To read a file faster, you need faster storage, which mostly means you're about to spend a lot of money.  Striping the backup across multiple disks in your backup software, or [RAID](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16816151121), or [SSD](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA29P1EC5324)'s, or SSD's in a RAID, or PCIe SSD's, or a RAMDisk; all will work.  Alternately, if you're using open source backup software, have it calculate the hash while it's writing the output.  I cannae change the laws of physics!

Comment: Hm, yeah, it seems that this is the truth. However, i will spare some time before i accept your answer in case someone else wants to add something.

Answer (score 7):

Old and already answered, but you may try to select specific chunks of file.

There is a perl solution i found somewhere and it that seems effective.
Basically the script performs MD5 on first 4KB for every 4MB block in file.

Note that because this "samples" the file, so it's not full proof, i.e. if say last 8 bytes of every 4MB chunk changes, it probably won't be caught by this hashing algo (depending on the size of last chunk).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw[ time ];
use Digest::MD5;

sub quickMD5 {
    my $fh = shift;
    my $md5 = new Digest::MD5->new;

    $md5->add( -s $fh );

    my $pos = 0;
    until( eof $fh ) {
        seek $fh, $pos, 0;
        read( $fh, my $block, 4096 ) or last;
        $md5->add( $block );
        $pos += 2048**2;
    }
    return $md5;
}

open FH, '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
printf "Processing $ARGV[0] : %u bytes\n", -s FH;

my $start = time;
my $qmd5 = quickMD5( *FH );
printf "Partial MD5 took %.6f seconds\n", time() - $start;
print "Partial MD5: ", $qmd5->hexdigest, "\n";
```

Comment: Hm, interesting idea! However, there will be a problem if only a small part of a file is corrupted after the first 4KB of a 2MB block.. But anyway, it is something nice that I didn't know!! Thanks for sharing!! :)

Comment: I usually do md5 of 3,4TB files that i DAILY copy to external storage. By now i had no surprises, btw with standard NAS performances full MD5, also given copy time, is not an option for me! Also consider you're doing MD5 of more than 250000/300000 data blocks, that SHOULD be acceptably safe with so large files.

Comment: How do I use this script to check the complete filesystem and write the results to a file instead of check just one file?

Comment: You'll just need to call it externally (ie with a bash script). Can't code right now but if you pipe the output of a "find" command on relevant folders of filesystem to the perl script should do the trick. in your bash script you should have something like "find /folder/ -type f | xargs perl_script" and redirect a to log file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the non-cryptographic hashes (ex: [xxhash](https://github.com/Cyan4973/xxHash) and [murmur3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)) they are much faster than md5 till of course you reach the max read speed.