# MD5 hash of huge files using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using  hashlib library (hashlib.md5() function) and its working fine with small file size in pySpark. The issue is - I have huge file around 2 TB and I would need to calculate md5 hash of this file. Is there any way in pyspark by leveraging distributed approach to achieve this ? my current method looks like below.

```
def md5_cal(row):
    file_contents = row[1]        
    md5_hash = hashlib.md5()
    md5_hash.update(file_contents.encode('utf-8'))  
    return md5_hash.hexdigest()

filepath = "my/HDFS/path"
md5_value = (sc.wholeTextFiles(filepath)).map(md5_cal).collect()
print("MD5 Hash:", md5_value )
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22748964/3238085  relevant answer. Hashes need to be computed on successive chunks of file in order which won't be possible in a distributed manner. You will have to roll out your own solution. wholeTextFile will read it as a one big file.

Comment: You cannot read a single binary file which is larger than 2GB into a single record. Here's the reasoning. https://community.databricks.com/t5/community-discussions/very-large-binary-files-ingestion-error-when-using-binaryfile/td-p/47440

Comment: spark supports distributed processing if i understand it correctly. not sure if any pySpark inbuilt function to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

A workflow that can help you achieve this.

Since this is a one large file of size 2 TB, you need to first split this into smaller chunks of say 1GB.

Reason for splitting is this :

https://community.databricks.com/t5/community-discussions/very-large-binary-files-ingestion-error-when-using-binaryfile/td-p/47440

> The error you're encountering is because the size of your binary file exceeds the maximum allowable length in Spark, which is 2147483647 bytes or approximately 2GB. The file you're trying to read is about 7GB, well beyond this limit.

To do the splitting efficiently, you can use lower level s3api of aws cli.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57353191/3238085  (source)

First, you need to know the size of the file so you can determine the byte ranges for each chunk. You can use the head-object command to get the metadata of the file, which includes its size.

> aws s3api head-object --bucket your-bucket-name --key path/to/your/large-file

Once you know the size of the file, you can start downloading it in chunks. You'll do this by specifying a byte range in the get-object command using the --range option. The range is specified in the format bytes=startByte-endByte.

For example, to download the first 1 MB (1,048,576 bytes) of a file, you can use the range bytes=0-1048575.

> aws s3api get-object --bucket your-bucket-name --key path/to/your/large-file --range bytes=0-1048575 chunk_000001.bin

Put all those chunks under a single s3 key. The file names of those chunk should be like

`[chunk_000001.bin, chunk_000002.bin ..... so on till ... chunk_010000.bin]`

You can automate the above process in a shell script and run this script on a EC2 machine located in the same region as your s3 file.

Do the following steps in Spark :

Read all those chunks in parallel on a large cluster with lot of memory.

Calculate md5sum of those chunks using map function into `md5sum_column`.

Then select `[filename, md5sum_column]` columns and sort by filename column. This is to ensure md5sum order matches with chunk filenames in order.

Collect all these md5sums we have calculate in the column `md5sum_column` into a list.

Join the strings to create a bigger string.

Then find hash of that string. This will give you final hash of the big 2TB file.

Comment: Thanks, I have some restriction to use other cloud services. my files are in restricted systems on on-premise

Comment: Then even better, you can do splitting on the same machine. https://superuser.com/a/160367/545870 Here's an example.

Comment: will this work in case of HDFS files? i want to ingest the same file to hive without splitting  once i compute MD5

Comment: It should work. Once you have calculated the hash, you can discard/delete the chunks you have created. Since you would want the 2TB file to be understood by your application, splitting willy nilly won't work for your application.

Comment: You can even try to read the big file in chunks of 128MB (since that's how HDFS stores any file) and calculate the hash in a streaming manner. here's an example. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14014877/3238085

Answer (score 0):

For a single huge file, using stock `hashlib.md5()`: Short answer is NO.

---

You will need to:

Optimize the read:

- by breaking down the file into smaller chunks OR
- by reading specific smaller chunks (byte-ranges) from one large file (e.g. if your file is in S3, then S3 read API allows you specify the start/end byte position to read from an S3 object)

Optimize the hash computation. E.g.:

- first compute hashes of all chunks in parallel, say using `hashlib.md5()`
- and then computes a single hash out of all chunk-hashes.

To optimize further you could take only X-bytes from each chunk to compute the hash, which is not full proof as it's like creating a hash out of a sample of bytes from the file instead of the whole file.

---

relation to `pyspark`: All of the above can be done using simple multi-threading / any-parallel-processing on say a bunch of lambda functions or a farm of EC2 instances. Spark is of course an option, but IMHO it's more a misuse of Spark. E.g. from a cost point of view a Spark cluster to do this would cost a LOT more than using lambda functions.

Answer (score 0):

objects uploaded to AWS S3 standard (not s3 express; as a single PUT to s3 *and* are not encrypted) use MD5 as their etag generation. That is: the etag *is* the MD5 checksum
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Object.html

Objects uploaded with the multipart API have an etag which is some merge (concatenation?) of all the etags of the individual blocks uploaded. And encrypted content: don't assume anything.

Most modern S3 clients use multipart above a few tens of MiB as it allows for parallel upload of blocks, is easier to retry and uses less client-side memory/disk for buffering.